# Getting the constant name of a controller from params[:controller]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, constants

I have

```
params[:controller] # => "posts/comments"
```

and I would like to get the constant name of the related controller:

```
Posts::CommentsController
```

I know I can make this:

```
"#{params[:controller].camelize}Controller".constantize # => Posts::CommentsController
```

I'm just asking if there is a dedicated Rails method to make this and, if so, what is that method?

Comment: Where do you need this functionality? In the controller, view, or somewhere else?

Comment: Use `self.class` in our controller or `"#{controller_path.camelize}Controller".constantize`

Comment: @Boris `self.class` doesn't returns the controller name in views and `controller_path` does not fit for my case. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
# path => "posts/comments"
recognized_path = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(path)

"#{recognized_path[:controller].camelize}Controller".constantize 
# => Posts::CommentsController
```

Please, update me if there is a dedicated Rails method to make this.